# Nested Controllers using UICollectionViewController reordering

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionViewController` nested inside. The collection view controller also has the `moveItemAt` method implemented, since I want the cells to be reorderable. So the cells have a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` attached. However, long press on the cells aren't happening. I can't seem to figure out if the nested controller is causing the gesture to be ignored. Maybe the parent controller is capturing the long press but that wouldn't make sense since AFAIK, gestures go up the view hierarchy, not the other way around.

For some context, I've used this method to nest my controllers

```
   func add(_ child: UIViewController) {
        addChildViewController(child)
        child.view.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

Comment: Where is your long press gesture? Are you adding it to the collectionView? If so, do you have your gesture handler implemented in your collection view controller?

Comment: The long press gesture is added by the UICollectionViewController when I implement "override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)". Each cell in the collectionView has a gesture recognizer. It's implemented out of the box, but doesn't seem to be triggering in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better approach...

Assuming you have a `UICollectionViewController` in your storyboard, and you've assigned the cell prototype to `DragMeCell` and set its Identifier to "DragMeCell" (and added a label connected to the `IBOutlet`), this should run and allow you to long-press drag-drop to reorder.

```
//
//  DragReorderCollectionViewController.swift
//  SW4Temp
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 7/25/18.
//

import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "DragMeCell"

class DragMeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!

}

class DragReorderCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    fileprivate var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

    fileprivate var dataArray = Array(0 ..< 25)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))

        if let cv = self.collectionView {
            cv.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
        }

    }

    @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        if let cv = self.collectionView,
            let gestureView = gesture.view {

            switch(gesture.state) {

            case .began:
                guard let selectedIndexPath = cv.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: cv)) else {
                    break
                }
                cv.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
            case .changed:
                cv.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gestureView))
            case .ended:
                cv.endInteractiveMovement()
            default:
                cv.cancelInteractiveMovement()
            }

        }

    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let i = dataArray[sourceIndexPath.item]
        dataArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
        dataArray.insert(i, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DragMeCell

        // Configure the cell
        cell.theLabel.text = "\(dataArray[indexPath.item])"

        return cell
    }

}
```

Then you can add it as a child view controller, using the code snippet you posted in your question.

Comment: Awesome, this is great. Do you have any idea why the long press didn't work in my approach? `installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement` was set to true for me.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you use "cv" in "beginInteractiveMovementForItem" and "gesture.view!" in "updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition". They seem to be the same object, that is the `UICollectionView`.

Comment: I missed that one - this was meant to be an example to build on, not finished code... but you're right --- `gesture.view!` *should* be unwrapped. I edited my answer.

Comment: Ah -- I see what you mean now with the default `installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement` not working when implementing childViewController... My assumption is "bug" because I can't find any documenting on it, but... If you loop through and print out the gesture recognizers *without* adding as child VC, you can see a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` listed. When adding as a child VC, that recognizer is not there. Curious.

Comment: With respect to `gesture.view`, is it possible that `self.collectionView` and `gesture.view` point to the same view object?

Comment: Yea, so regarding`installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement`, it seems like manually adding a `UICollectionViewController` as a child VC causes problems with the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. I was actually able to print out gesture recognizers attached to the _child_ VC. Which means they're there but aren't triggerring. Maybe these gesture recognizers have to live at the parent level to be triggered? But that wouldn't make sense.